# What are the differences among "bubbles", "suds" and "foam"?

Tags: difference

What are the differences among "bubbles", "suds" and "foam"?

From my understanding,

"bubbles"means the round, individual and see-through ones. "bubbles" can float in the air.

"suds" can not be individual ones. they are mass of bubbles. And they come from the soap or other cleanings. "suds" can not float in the air. they must attach to some surfaces.

"foam" can not be individual ones too. they are mass of bubbles too. they can be caused by chemical things. because of the small tiny bubbles, "foam" can not be see-through. Also, they can not float in the air.

They are my understandings. Am I right?

Could you give me some examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"A bubble" is a single hollow sphere of some substance, usually containing a gas or otherwise temporary. It is not necessarily transparent, and it does not necessarily float through the air. "A bubble" can also be somewhat idiomatic for a secluded or otherwise separated group. E.G. "He lives in a bubble of conservatives." "Bubbles" is the plural form (i.e. not an individual bubble). If I understand correctly, you meant "individual" here to mean separated by space (because foam is also made of individual bubbles). This is a correct way to use it, but one can also use "bubbles" where one would use "foam".

Your interpretations of "suds" and "foam" are correct: both words are interchangeable, but "suds" implies that they were produced by soap. Another difference is that "foam" can also describe a type of material (e.g. Styrofoam, a foam mattress, ect.).